# Javascript setTimeout ignoring time parameter

Tags: javascript, settimeout

It's not the first time I've used setTimeout(), but I can't figure out what the problem is. The code part of the setTimeout() is executing correctly, but it is executing immediately without the delay. If anyone can see the problem, that would help. Here's the code:

```
if(token==1){
    img1.src=ssImages[imgNum];
    num1=0;
    num2=10;
    setTimeout('crossFade()',2500);
}
```

Comment: Your are calling to a function not a string?
`setTimeout(crossFade,2500);`

Comment: @Igor Dymov: No, that was not the same issue.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo, because the timeout itself [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/JAU2Z/).

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure this is the code? If it executes immediately there are usually two reasons:

1. The developer thought the time is specified in seconds - but 2500 is fine, that's 2.5 seconds.
2. He calls the function immediately (e.g. `setTimeout(foo(), 1234)`);

But none of the reasons apply to your code so check the rest of the code if there are any other calls to that function.

---

Anyway, you should really pass a function instead of a string:

```
setTimeout(crossFade, 2500);
```

Or, if you need to specify any arguments:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    crossFade(...);
}, 2500);
```

Comment: @ratSawGod: Which info exactly should not be disseminated any further? Anything ThiefMaster said is 100% correct. *"does not work"* is not a helpful error description. We can only work with what you give us and so far, you only give us this one line `setTimeout('crossFade()',2500);`, which works perfectly. Create a more complete example that demonstrates your problem. And please don't be rude. Other people are spending their valuable time in order to help *you*.

Comment: Anonymous functions are the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Theifmaster. The window. setTimeout method takes two arguments:

1) Function OR Expression
2) Time in ms

In your code you provide a string or an Expression :

setTimeout('crossFade()',....)

This is generally discouraged as with the use of eval. You should pass a function - either named:

setTimeout(crossFade,....)

OR as suggested anonymous:

setTimeout(function(){crossFade()},....

This is about all you can do to trouble shoot this code unless you provide an example ok jsfiddle for us to see the context this is called.